# How to validate a line if followed by a specifc line?

Tags: bash, text-processing, grep

On some our Linux servers we have the following files:

```
/etc/ambari-agent/conf/ambari-agent.ini
```

The files include the following example of lines:

```
; memory_threshold_soft_mb=400
; memory_threshold_hard_mb=1000
; ignore_mount_points=/mnt/custom1,/mnt/custom2

[security]
force_https_protocol=PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2
keysdir=/var/lib/ambari-agent/keys
server_crt=ca.crt
passphrase_env_var_name=AMBARI_PASSPHRASE
```

what we want to do is to verify the full match of the line - `force_https_protocol=PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2` under `[security]`

so we did the following  ( this line is part of bash script )

```
[[ `  grep -xA 0 "force_https_protocol=PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2" /etc/ambari-agent/conf/ambari-agent.ini | wc -l ` -eq 1 ]] && echo "full match"
```

this works but we not sure if our approach is the right full match

I will happy to get other ideas

The target is to verify if the line `force_https_protocol=PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2` appears after the line - `[security]` ( this is must ) , and need to also verify that line is fully matched with `force_https_protocol=PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2`

Comment: What are you trying to verify exactly? Your command simply confirms that there is exactly one line in your file with the content `force_https_protocol=PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2`. It does not check that this line occurs inside the "security" section. Is that something you need? You are also making the command more complicated than necessary since `-A 0` means "don't include any lines after the match in the output" which is what the default behavior of `grep` is anyway. But please [edit] and explain what you want to verify. What if there are >1 match? What if the match is not in the expected section?

Comment: see the update ( the last line )

Comment: So you don't need it to be the first line after `[security]`? It can be anywhere as long as it is after `[security]`? And you are counting the output, why? Do you also need to ensure there is exactly one match, not more? Finally, can you have any whitespace around the target line? Can it be `<space>force_https_protocol=PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2` or `force_https_protocol=PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2    `?

Comment: no , we need to verify the line after [security] !

Comment: and yes we need exactly match of force_https_protocol=PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `grep` and enabling PCRE in this way:

```
<infile grep -zqP '\[security\]\nforce_https_protocol=PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2\n' \
    && echo "found" || echo "not found"
```

in case that if that line was not immediately after `[security]`, just change

`\[security\]\n` with `\[security\]\n.*\n` in the command.

---

to making sure it only appear once, you can add `-c` option for the grep and verify it.

```
[[ $(grep -zcP '\[security\]\nforce_https_protocol=PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2\n' infile) -eq 1 ]] && echo found
```

or equivalently:

```
(($(grep -zcP '\[security\]\nforce_https_protocol=PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2\n' infile) == 1)) && echo found
```

Answer (score 1):

You can parse that INI file with gnu awk:

```c
gawk '
    match($0, /^\[(.+)\]$/, m) {is_security = m[1] == "security"}
    is_security && $0 == "force_https_protocol=PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2" {valid=1; exit}
    END {
        if (valid) {print "valid"} else {print "not valid"}
        exit (!valid)
    }
' file.ini
```